# Typing in Terminal causes Daisy-Chained monitors to cut off on on

Tags: multiple-monitors, xps, 17.04

I have a dell xps13, and I'm daisy chaining two dell U2515H monitors through displayport. This works fine.

However when I type in terminal, both the monitors seem to go off and then back on after a second or two. This only happens when I type in terminal.

Any idea what could be the cause of this?

EDIT:

/var/log/Xorg.0.log log

```
[     6.296] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:4041.0004/input/input9/event7"
[     6.296] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech MX Master" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[     6.296] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[     6.296] (**) Logitech MX Master: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[     6.296] (**) Logitech MX Master: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     6.296] (**) Logitech MX Master: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     6.296] (II) input device 'Logitech MX Master', /dev/input/event7 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
[     6.296] (II) Device 'Logitech MX Master' set to 1000 DPI
[     6.296] (II) input device 'Logitech MX Master', /dev/input/event7 is a pointer caps
[     6.296] (II) input device 'Logitech MX Master', /dev/input/event7 is a keyboard
[     6.296] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech MX Master (/dev/input/mouse1)
[     6.296] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     6.296] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     6.297] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech K830 (/dev/input/event6)
[     6.297] (**) Logitech K830: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[     6.297] (**) Logitech K830: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     6.297] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech K830'
[     6.297] (**) Logitech K830: always reports core events
[     6.297] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[     6.297] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     6.297] (II) input device 'Logitech K830', /dev/input/event6 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
[     6.297] (II) input device 'Logitech K830', /dev/input/event6 is a pointer caps
[     6.297] (II) input device 'Logitech K830', /dev/input/event6 is a keyboard
[     6.312] (II) libinput: Logitech K830: needs a virtual subdevice
[     6.312] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:404C.0005/input/input8/event6"
[     6.312] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech K830" (type: MOUSE, id 11)
[     6.312] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[     6.312] (**) Logitech K830: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[     6.312] (**) Logitech K830: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     6.312] (**) Logitech K830: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     6.312] (II) input device 'Logitech K830', /dev/input/event6 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
[     6.312] (II) input device 'Logitech K830', /dev/input/event6 is a pointer caps
[     6.312] (II) input device 'Logitech K830', /dev/input/event6 is a keyboard
[     6.312] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech K830 (/dev/input/mouse0)
[     6.312] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     6.312] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     6.312] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Integrated_Webcam_HD (/dev/input/event12)
[     6.312] (**) Integrated_Webcam_HD: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     6.312] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Integrated_Webcam_HD'
[     6.312] (**) Integrated_Webcam_HD: always reports core events
[     6.312] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event12"
[     6.312] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     6.313] (II) input device 'Integrated_Webcam_HD', /dev/input/event12 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     6.313] (II) input device 'Integrated_Webcam_HD', /dev/input/event12 is a keyboard
[     6.352] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input13/event12"
[     6.352] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Integrated_Webcam_HD" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[     6.352] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     6.352] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[     6.352] (II) input device 'Integrated_Webcam_HD', /dev/input/event12 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     6.352] (II) input device 'Integrated_Webcam_HD', /dev/input/event12 is a keyboard
[     6.352] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad (/dev/input/event13)
[     6.352] (**) DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[     6.352] (**) DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[     6.352] (**) DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[     6.352] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[     6.352] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[     6.352] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     6.352]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.9.0
[     6.352]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[     6.352]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[     6.353] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad'
[     6.353] (**) DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: always reports core events
[     6.353] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event13"
[     6.384] (II) synaptics: DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: found clickpad property
[     6.384] (--) synaptics: DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: x-axis range 0 - 1216 (res 12)
[     6.384] (--) synaptics: DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: y-axis range 0 - 680 (res 12)
[     6.384] (II) synaptics: DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: device does not report pressure, will use touch data.
[     6.384] (II) synaptics: DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: device does not report finger width.
[     6.384] (--) synaptics: DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: buttons: left double triple
[     6.384] (--) synaptics: DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: Vendor 0x6cb Product 0x76af
[     6.384] (--) synaptics: DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: invalid pressure range.  defaulting to 0 - 255
[     6.384] (--) synaptics: DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: invalid finger width range.  defaulting to 0 - 15
[     6.384] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[     6.384] (--) synaptics: DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: touchpad found
[     6.384] (**) DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: always reports core events
[     6.420] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-8/i2c-DLL075B:01/0018:06CB:76AF.0006/input/input15/event13"
[     6.420] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 13)
[     6.420] (**) synaptics: DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[     6.420] (**) synaptics: DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[     6.420] (**) synaptics: DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.144
[     6.420] (**) DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[     6.420] (**) DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[     6.420] (**) DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     6.420] (**) DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     6.420] (--) synaptics: DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: touchpad found
[     6.420] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse3)
[     6.420] (**) DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[     6.421] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Intel Virtual Button driver (/dev/input/event10)
[     6.421] (**) Intel Virtual Button driver: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     6.421] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Intel Virtual Button driver'
[     6.421] (**) Intel Virtual Button driver: always reports core events
[     6.421] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event10"
[     6.421] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     6.421] (II) input device 'Intel Virtual Button driver', /dev/input/event10 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     6.421] (II) input device 'Intel Virtual Button driver', /dev/input/event10 is a keyboard
[     6.436] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/INT33D6:00/input/input11/event10"
[     6.436] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Intel Virtual Button driver" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
[     6.436] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     6.436] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[     6.436] (II) input device 'Intel Virtual Button driver', /dev/input/event10 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     6.436] (II) input device 'Intel Virtual Button driver', /dev/input/event10 is a keyboard
[     6.436] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic (/dev/input/event14)
[     6.436] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     6.436] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     6.436] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event15)
[     6.436] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     6.436] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     6.437] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event16)
[     6.437] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     6.437] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     6.437] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event17)
[     6.437] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     6.437] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     6.437] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Intel HID events (/dev/input/event9)
[     6.437] (**) Intel HID events: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     6.437] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Intel HID events'
[     6.437] (**) Intel HID events: always reports core events
[     6.437] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event9"
[     6.437] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     6.437] (II) input device 'Intel HID events', /dev/input/event9 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     6.437] (II) input device 'Intel HID events', /dev/input/event9 is a keyboard
[     6.452] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/INT33D5:00/input/input10/event9"
[     6.452] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Intel HID events" (type: KEYBOARD, id 15)
[     6.452] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     6.452] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[     6.452] (II) input device 'Intel HID events', /dev/input/event9 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     6.452] (II) input device 'Intel HID events', /dev/input/event9 is a keyboard
[     6.452] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[     6.452] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     6.452] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[     6.452] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[     6.452] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[     6.452] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     6.452] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     6.452] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[     6.468] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/event4"
[     6.468] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 16)
[     6.468] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     6.468] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[     6.468] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     6.468] (II) input device 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard', /dev/input/event4 is a keyboard
[     6.468] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event8)
[     6.468] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[     6.468] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[     6.468] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[     6.468] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[     6.468] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[     6.468] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[     6.500] (II) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: found clickpad property
[     6.500] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: x-axis range 1276 - 5666 (res 0)
[     6.500] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: y-axis range 1118 - 4734 (res 0)
[     6.500] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: pressure range 0 - 255
[     6.500] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: finger width range 0 - 15
[     6.500] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: buttons: left double triple
[     6.500] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x7
[     6.500] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[     6.500] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[     6.500] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[     6.548] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6/event8"
[     6.548] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 17)
[     6.548] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[     6.548] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[     6.548] (**) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.035
[     6.548] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[     6.548] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[     6.548] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     6.548] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     6.548] (--) synaptics: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: touchpad found
[     6.548] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse2)
[     6.548] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[     6.549] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Dell WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event11)
[     6.549] (**) Dell WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     6.549] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Dell WMI hotkeys'
[     6.549] (**) Dell WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[     6.549] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event11"
[     6.549] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     6.549] (II) input device 'Dell WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event11 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     6.549] (II) input device 'Dell WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event11 is a keyboard
[     6.568] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input12/event11"
[     6.568] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Dell WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 18)
[     6.568] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     6.568] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[     6.568] (II) input device 'Dell WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event11 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     6.568] (II) input device 'Dell WMI hotkeys', /dev/input/event11 is a keyboard
[     6.598] (**) Logitech MX Master: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[     6.598] (**) Logitech MX Master: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     6.598] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech MX Master'
[     6.598] (**) Logitech MX Master: always reports core events
[     6.598] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[     6.598] (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
[     6.598] (II) libinput: Logitech MX Master: is a virtual subdevice
[     6.598] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:4041.0004/input/input9/event7"
[     6.598] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech MX Master" (type: KEYBOARD, id 19)
[     6.598] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     6.598] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[     6.598] (**) Logitech K830: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[     6.598] (**) Logitech K830: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     6.598] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech K830'
[     6.598] (**) Logitech K830: always reports core events
[     6.598] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[     6.598] (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
[     6.598] (II) libinput: Logitech K830: is a virtual subdevice
[     6.598] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:404C.0005/input/input8/event6"
[     6.598] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech K830" (type: KEYBOARD, id 20)
[     6.598] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     6.598] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[     7.322] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1-1-8 has no monitor section
[     7.322] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1-1-1 has no monitor section
[     7.322] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1-1 has no monitor section
[     7.323] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SHP", prod id 5193
[     7.323] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[     7.323] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 -hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz eP)
[     7.355] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SHP", prod id 5193
[     7.355] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[     7.355] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 -hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz eP)
[     9.383] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SHP", prod id 5193
[     9.384] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[     9.384] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 -hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz eP)
[     9.505] (II) modeset(0): Allocate new frame buffer 7040x1440 stride
[     9.841] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SHP", prod id 5193
[     9.841] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[     9.841] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 -hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz eP)
[     9.898] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SHP", prod id 5193
[     9.898] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[     9.898] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 -hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz eP)
[    11.841] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SHP", prod id 5193
[    11.841] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    11.841] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 -hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz eP)
[    15.000] (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech MX Master
[    15.002] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    15.002] (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech MX Master
[    15.021] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    15.095] (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech K830
[    15.099] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    15.099] (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech K830
[    15.125] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    15.331] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech MX Master (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    15.331] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    15.331] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    15.339] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech K830 (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    15.339] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    15.339] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    15.383] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech MX Master (/dev/input/event6)
[    15.383] (**) Logitech MX Master: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    15.383] (**) Logitech MX Master: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    15.383] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech MX Master'
[    15.383] (**) Logitech MX Master: always reports core events
[    15.383] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[    15.383] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    15.384] (II) input device 'Logitech MX Master', /dev/input/event6 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
[    15.384] (II) Device 'Logitech MX Master' set to 1000 DPI
[    15.384] (II) input device 'Logitech MX Master', /dev/input/event6 is a pointer caps
[    15.384] (II) input device 'Logitech MX Master', /dev/input/event6 is a keyboard
[    15.404] (II) libinput: Logitech MX Master: needs a virtual subdevice
[    15.404] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0009/0003:046D:4041.000A/input/input24/event6"
[    15.404] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech MX Master" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[    15.404] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    15.405] (**) Logitech MX Master: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    15.405] (**) Logitech MX Master: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    15.405] (**) Logitech MX Master: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    15.405] (II) input device 'Logitech MX Master', /dev/input/event6 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
[    15.405] (II) Device 'Logitech MX Master' set to 1000 DPI
[    15.405] (II) input device 'Logitech MX Master', /dev/input/event6 is a pointer caps
[    15.405] (II) input device 'Logitech MX Master', /dev/input/event6 is a keyboard
[    15.405] (**) Logitech MX Master: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    15.405] (**) Logitech MX Master: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    15.405] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech MX Master'
[    15.405] (**) Logitech MX Master: always reports core events
[    15.405] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[    15.405] (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
[    15.405] (II) libinput: Logitech MX Master: is a virtual subdevice
[    15.405] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0009/0003:046D:4041.000A/input/input24/event6"
[    15.405] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech MX Master" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    15.405] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    15.405] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    15.405] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[    15.405] (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
[    15.406] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech K830 (/dev/input/event7)
[    15.406] (**) Logitech K830: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    15.406] (**) Logitech K830: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    15.406] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech K830'
[    15.406] (**) Logitech K830: always reports core events
[    15.406] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[    15.406] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    15.406] (II) input device 'Logitech K830', /dev/input/event7 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
[    15.406] (II) input device 'Logitech K830', /dev/input/event7 is a pointer caps
[    15.406] (II) input device 'Logitech K830', /dev/input/event7 is a keyboard
[    15.440] (II) libinput: Logitech K830: needs a virtual subdevice
[    15.440] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0009/0003:046D:404C.000B/input/input25/event7"
[    15.440] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech K830" (type: MOUSE, id 19)
[    15.441] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    15.442] (**) Logitech K830: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    15.442] (**) Logitech K830: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    15.442] (**) Logitech K830: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    15.443] (II) input device 'Logitech K830', /dev/input/event7 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Mouse
[    15.443] (II) input device 'Logitech K830', /dev/input/event7 is a pointer caps
[    15.443] (II) input device 'Logitech K830', /dev/input/event7 is a keyboard
[    15.443] (**) Logitech K830: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    15.443] (**) Logitech K830: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    15.443] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Logitech K830'
[    15.443] (**) Logitech K830: always reports core events
[    15.443] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[    15.443] (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
[    15.444] (II) libinput: Logitech K830: is a virtual subdevice
[    15.444] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0009/0003:046D:404C.000B/input/input25/event7"
[    15.444] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech K830" (type: KEYBOARD, id 20)
[    15.444] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    15.444] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[    15.444] (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
[    15.444] (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
[    16.098] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SHP", prod id 5193
[    16.099] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    16.099] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 -hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz eP)
[ 13929.529] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SHP", prod id 5193
[ 13929.529] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[ 13929.529] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  138.50  1920 1968 2000 2080  1080 1083 1088 1111 -hsync -vsync (66.6 kHz eP)
```

Comment: Can you post the according lines within '/var/log/Xorg.0.log'?

Comment: added to the question. tar